# How can I process Credit cards on my Magento store?

Tags: magento-1.9, pci

My Magento store is PCI complaint. I don't like redirecting customers from my store to bank's website for entering credit/debit card details. Is there any way I can collect the card information on my store and then pass it onto banks' website so that customers just have to enter the 3D-secure PIN?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I suggest that you look into integrating with a payment gateway module; we've used Authorize.net for our clients and integrated it to the point that checkout is completely conducted on the site. The information is then sent to Authorize.net and they process it. We've used the `ParadoxLabs_AuthorizeNetCim` module for this.